# .NET Core MVC controller exception handling and program flow

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.1

I am wondering what is considered "best practice" in regards to how to structure my MVC controller methods to have them play along nicely with my service layer and data repository layer when the data requested is not found.

I have read quite a bit about how to not use exceptions to control program flow.  And yet I have seen many examples where the code is structured as shown below...

In the case of a GetById controller method for example, and the id doesn't exist - should the service layer throw an exception?  Should the data layer repository throw an exception?  Then the controller should catch that?  Or is that considered bad practice?

For example here is my controller:

```
public IActionResult Get(int id)
{
    EmployeeViewModel pool;
    try
    {
        employee = _employeeService.GetEmployeeById(id);
    }
    catch (KeyNotFoundException e) 
    {
        return NotFound(e.message);
    }
    return Ok();
}
```

And here is my service layer method:

```
public EmployeeViewModel GetEmployeeById(int id)
{
   var employee = _employeeRepository.GetEmployeeById(id);
   if(employee == null)
        throw new KeyNotFoundException("Employee not found"); // ok?

   var employeelViewModel = Mapper.Map<Employee, EmployeeViewModel>(employee);

    return employeeViewModel;
}
```

And here is the data repository method:

```
public Employee GetEmployeeById(int id)
{
     var employee =_context.Employees.SingleOrDefault(e => e.Id == id);

     if(employee == null)
        throw new KeyNotFoundException("Employee with given id does not exist"); // ok?

     return employee;

}
```

Or should I just create an additional service/repo method to first check if that object with that id exists in the controller and not worry about throwing the exceptions in the service layer or the data repository layer.

Eg.

```
public ActionResult Get(int id)
{
    if (id == 0)
        return BadRequest(new ApiResponse("Invalid EmployeeId"));

    if (!_employeeService.EmployeeExists(id))
            return NotFound("Employee not found"));

    employees = _employeeService.GetEmployeeById(id);
        return Ok(employees);
}
```

Service layer methods:

```
public bool EmployeeExists(int id)
{
    return _employeeRepository.EmployeeExists(id);
}

public EmployeeViewModel GetEmployeeById(int id)
{
    var employee = _employeeRepository.GetEmployeeById(id);
    // no check for null or throwing exception
    var employeelViewModel = Mapper.Map<Employee, EmployeeViewModel>(employee);

    return employeeViewModel;
```

}

And data repository methods:

```
public bool EmployeeExists(int id)
{
    return _context.Employees.Count(c => c.Id == id) > 0;
}

public Employee GetEmployeeById(int id)
{
     // no check for null or throwing exception
     return _context.Employees.SingleOrDefault(e => e.Id == id);
}
```

Comment: Exceptions can be heavy if not used correctly. It really "depends". Personally I just return null if the entity cannot be found, then check for null in the controller: `if(entity == null) return NotFound();`

Comment: @mxmissile Thanks - yes in some scenarios this would suffice.  In some of my service and repository methods though I may be fetching related info that requires the employee.  For example, there may be a controller method to get Employee history.  In the service layer or data layer, if the wrong Employee id is passed in then the service and the data repository will return null.  There's no way of knowing if the employee id is correct without either throwing the null exception or having a separate repository method to check first if that item exists.